# How to enter parameters in an interactive way from batch file to jar file?

Tags: java, batch-file

I want to run a jar file from batch file and then after running this jar file it will start asking some question for example it will ask about inserting working directory and after inserting the working directory it will ask about the name of file it should look for in this working directory and in the next step it will ask about the method of processing this file and ...

I have written this code in my .bat file

```
@echo off
set "workingdirectory=C:\MyResult"
set "filename=result.txt"
set "processingmethod=methodD"
cd C:\JavaFolder
java -jar myjavacode.jar "%workingdirectory% %filename% %methodD%
```

but these steps just run the jar file but they don't pass the arguments needed for going to the next steps.

My question is that is there any way to do all these steps automatically by the use of bat file?

Comment: Did you make use of `String[] args` in `public static void main(String[] args)` for passing the parameters?

Comment: Don't you mean "then before running this jar file" instead of " then after running this jar file"?

Answer (score 0):

You can read input from the user with [set /p](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490998.aspx):

```
SET /P "workingdirectory=Please enter working directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off 
set /p workingdirectory=Enter working dir
set /p filename=Enter file name
set /p processingmethod=Enter processing method
cd C:\JavaFolder java -jar myjavacode.jar %workingdirectory% %filename% %processingmethod%
```